Knock-Out (KO) Mice
We have generated an induced KO mice line for a specific gene. However when i perform IF staining I can still see substantial levels of the protein for this specific gene produced, even though the Genotyping results indicate that the gene KO was successfully performed. Did anyone else have the same problem? or can you think of a plausible explanation to this problem? Thank you in advance!

How is the knockout induced? When was it induced? When are you measuring protein?

Mice are induced by a 16 day administration of doxycycline via the drinking water. The study model is then initiated after a 7-days wash-out (restore to normal water) phase. I measure the protein at day 10, so in total 17 days after the interruption of induction.

How are you measuring protein levels? What controls have you performed?

At the moment, running the initial phase of the experiments, we are comparing the protein expression to the wild type animals by performing the same IF staining on both groups. The protein signal is not significantly different in KO mice as compared to the wild type ones.

Are the knockouts homozygous? Is the antibody known to be specific enough for this particular protein, without affinity to related proteins? Do you know anything about the half-life of the protein?

Yes they are homozygous and the antibody does not have affinity to other related proteins

Based on previous studies we have eliminated the possibility that it could be caused due to the short half-life of the protein.

Well, a long half-life would be potentially more of a problem here than a short one... I'd recommend using other methods to identify your protein and measure gene expression and see if they agree. Maybe start with PCR. Possible issues I can think of are that your mice are not actually KO mice; maybe they have a separate working copy of the gene you're targeting even if your construct is present. Your induction isn't working: wrong concentration of doxy, animal care staff are exchanging with normal water, etc. Or measurement: cross-reactivity, non-specific binding, etc.

what is the actual mutation, it's a degron construct or something? Can you exclude e.g. stop codon readthrough if not? having RT-PCR data might help if the KO is DNA/transcriptional. Do you have Sanger data of the chromosomal locus to exclude the possibility that the mutation is wrong? Antibody cross reactivity is also a good note, especially in the case of a functional paralog or something.
